# Approximating a conical frustum with binary search algorithm

Tags: c++, math, binary-search

I'm trying to solve [this](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1549) problem.

The description states that some friends have a bottle of coke and they want to equally divide it in cups and I need to help the group to split the Coke bottle.

To solve this I need the height **h** such that, if each cup is filled with Coke up to the height h, then each person gets the same amount of coke. You may assume that no cup will needed to be filled more than its capacity.

The information given to me is the radius of the top and bottom of the cup with its height.

Input description:

> The first line of input contains an integer C that determines the number of test cases. Each test case starts with a line containing two integers, N and L (1 ≤ N ≤ 100, 1 ≤ L ≤ 10^8), the number of friends in the group and the amount of Coke in the bottle, in milliliters. The second line contains three integers b, B and H (1 ≤ b ≤ B ≤ 100, 1 ≤ H ≤ 100), the radius of the smaller and the larger base, and the height of the cups, in centimeters.

The output description :

> For each test case, print the value of h such that all cups must be filled up to the height h cm. Print the answer with 2 decimal places.

Example of Input:

> 2
>   1 200
>   5 6 8
>   2 350
>   3 3 16

Example of Output:

> 2.40
>   6.19

My solution.

With the data given in the question it was necessary to find the radius of the top of the coke amount (like a frustum inside a frustum O.o where the data given correspond to the outside frustum)

With the radius of the coke amount the binary search algorithm can 'guess' the best h.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define EPS 0.001

typedef long long lld;

int main(){
    lld c,n,l,b,B,H; //names are described in the input
    scanf("%lld",&c);
    for (lld i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
        scanf("%lld %lld %lld %lld %lld",&n,&l,&b,&B,&H);

        double v = l/n;//volume expected for each cup
        double ini = 0,fim = H, mid = 0.0; //mid will be the 'h'
        double v_approximate = 0;
        while(fabs(v - v_approximate) > EPS){
            mid = (ini + fim)/2.0;

            double tmp = b + (B-b)*mid/H; //this is the radius of the coke top
            v_approximate = (M_PI*mid/3.0)*(tmp*tmp + tmp*b + b*b);

            if(v_approximate == v)
                break;
            else if(v_approximate > v)
                fim = mid;
            else
                ini = mid;
        }
        printf("%.2lf\n",mid);
    }
}
```

This code gives 10% of wrong answer. This is the first time that i tried to use approximation to solve a math question. What am i missing ?

Comment: Can you give an example of a case when it gives the wrong answer?

Comment: No =( I don't know where it gives wrong answer. This problem is exclusive of this website... I can't find any input on the web.

Comment: Do you get the same percentage wrong if you change `EPS`?

Comment: Yep. I've tried this value 0.00000001. Even without EPS it's 10% ... I've made a for loop that calculate mid 100 times.

Comment: @puwi `if(v_approximate == v)`  Comparing floating point values for equality is a mistake, all due to the inexactness of such numbers.

Comment: @puwi `if(v_approximate == v)`  https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That comparison doesn't appear to be important. It could be removed. So, that doesn't answer why the code is not working 10% of the time.

Comment: OH Guys T.T .... i've got accepted ... the error was using long long with division... the result was an integer ... i've corrected it changing all values to double ....

Comment: Thanks for the help =) you all deserve a cup of coke.